# Getting an exception while trying to receive objects over TCP with c#

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp

I am trying to receive `objects` with `TCP` using `C#` and `serialization`. I am receiving `objects` constantly and each `object` is sent to a new task.  I chose not to use `threads` because its too expensive.  The problem is that if I am receiving only 1 `object` at a time everything goes just fine but if I am trying to receive more than 1 `object`, after a few seconds I am getting: 
`"the input stream is not a valid binary format. the starting contents (in bytes) are: ..."`

This is my listening function:

```
public void Listen()
        {
            try
            {
                TcpObject tcpObject = new TcpObject();
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                bool offline = true;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(() => offline = Offline));

                while (!offline)
                {
                    tcpObject = (TcpObject)formatter.Deserialize(serverStream);

                    if (tcpObject.Command == Command.Transfer)
                    {
                        #region Task
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            SentAntenna sentAntenna = (SentAntenna)tcpObject.Object;

                            string antennaName = sentAntenna.Name;

                            if (MainWindow.SpectrumList.ContainsKey(antennaName))
                            {
                                PointCollection pointCollection = new PointCollection();
                                float minChan = sentAntenna.Min;
                                float maxChan = sentAntenna.Max;

                                if (MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.AbsoluteMinimum == -1)
                                {
                                    Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                        new Action(delegate
                                        {
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.AbsoluteMinimum = minChan;
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.AbsoluteMaximum = maxChan;
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.TBMinRange = minChan.ToString();
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.TBMaxRange = maxChan.ToString();
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.MinRange = minChan;
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.MaxRange = maxChan;
                                            MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.UpdateRange();
                                        }));
                                }

                                float gap = maxChan - minChan;
                                foreach (Frequency f in sentAntenna.Frequencies)
                                {
                                    float chan = ((f.Channel - minChan) / gap) * 310;
                                    float inten = ((f.Intensity - 1) / 599) * 100;
                                    pointCollection.Add(new Point(chan, inten));
                                }

                                pointCollection.Freeze();
                                Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                    new Action(() => MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.AllAntennaPoints = pointCollection.Clone()));
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(50);
                        });
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // raise an event
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should be able to cut out almost *everything* from this code - write a small console app which just deserializes objects and prints minimal diagnostics. Ideally, then post a short but complete pair of programs demonstrating the problem.

Comment: could you tell us what you actualy have to do? Why did you make Task`s in while loop? and set variable with Dispatcher invoke?

Comment: The Dispatcher.Invoke calls are clearly to update bound UI elements in the MainWindow. I would suspect he's going with the tasks because he is "receiving objects constantly" and doesn't want the reception of data slowed down by the processing of each object.

Comment: Thanks @Pete thats what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
SentAntenna sentAntenna = (SentAntenna)tcpObject.Object;
```

to the line before the StartNew(). I believe this will fix your issue.

I don't think you want concurrent access to the tcpObject, since it's global to all the tasks.

Alternatively you could instantiate the TcpObject inside the while loop, which would then keep it local to each task.

Comment: Tried moving this line of code but the problem remains the same, and i dont think there is a concurrent access to the tcpObject because each while loop iteration the object resets to another instance.

Comment: @Slava Zoref The objects are being shared because tcpObject is being declared outside the while loop. While it's being re-instantiated, the scope is global across all tasks. You need to declare it within the while loop so that each task will get its own copy. (See the bottom Page 51 of the CSharp guide referring to the scope of the variable: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222).

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this error:

1. When two objects concurently writes to one connection
2. When somthing goes wrong with serverStream: stream have received a part of data or received 0 length data
3. You concurently acces to tcpObject. it's a bad idea.